# Angularjs + semantic UI multiple select

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to style my multiple select dropdown element like [Semantic UI's example](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html), but my implementation seems to use some odd combination of the styling from Semantic's form fields and the [multiple select from Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) (the field is scrollable and I can select multiple options in the same manner as the example in the docs). What is the proper way to use styling from Semantic while binding correctly to my Angular model?

```
<div class="field">
  <select multiple
          name="race"
          ng-model="user.profile.race"
          class="ui dropdown">
          <option value="AI"> American Indian or Alaskan Native </option>
          <option value="AA"> African American or Black </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!